# Elementary set theory - are these sets empty?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals

we are asked to answer if the following statements are true or false, and why:

1) The set ${\{\emptyset\}^{\mathbb N}}$ has exactly $1$ element.

2) The set ${{\emptyset}^{\mathbb N}}$ is empty.

3) The set ${\mathbb N}^{\emptyset}$ is empty

4) $(\{1,2,3\}^{\mathbb N})$-$\{1,2\}^{\mathbb N}$=$\{3\}^{\mathbb N}$

What I tried doing:

I tried using the fact that $|A^B|=|A|^{|B|}$, so for the first question we get $1^{\aleph0}$ = 1

For the second question, same thing, we get $0$, but for the third question, we have a problem...I think that set is empty, but when I look at $\aleph0 ^0$ it should be 1...

Comment: If anyone can help me find the many duplicates of this question that abound (and it's been asked at least four times in the last week or two), I'd be obliged!

Comment: $X^{Y}$ can be identified as the set of functions $Y\rightarrow X$. That makes it easyer. Alephs don't have to be used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is exactly one map $\mathbb N\to\{\emptyset\}$, given by $f(n)=\emptyset$.

There is no map $\mathbb N\to\emptyset$ as we cannot have e.g. $f(1)\in\emptyset$.

There is exactly one map $\emptyset\to\mathbb N$. If you give me an element of $\emptyset$, I am willing to name you a natural number.

For 4 just pick e.g. a surjection $\mathbb N\to\{1,2,3\}$.

Comment: If homsets are assumed to be disjoint then the sets $\left\{ 1,2,3\right\} ^{\mathbb{N}}=\mathbf{Set}\left(\mathbb{N},\left\{ 1,2,3\right\} \right)$
and $\left\{ 3\right\} ^{\mathbb{N}}=\mathbf{Set}\left(\mathbb{N},\left\{ 3\right\} \right)$
are automatically disjoint. But the tags of the question make me wonder if that is a smart thing to say here. What do you think?

Answer (score 0):

Your reasoning about questions 1 and 2 is correct.

For question 3, note that for any set $X$, there exists a unique function $\emptyset \rightarrow X$, namely the [empty function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empty_function). This may seem counterintuitive at first, but keep thinking about it and it will start seeming more sensible & obvious. Anyway, the set of all functions $\emptyset \rightarrow X$ always has precisely one element, namely the empty function, and therefore $|X^\emptyset|=1.$ Let me reiterate: this becomes more intuitive the more you think about it.

I won't give you the answer to question 4, but here's a hint. You can think of  $X^\mathbb{N}$ as the set of all sequences in $X$. Now consider the sequence $(1,2,3,1,2,3,1,\cdots) \in \{1,2,3\}^\mathbb{N}.$